# Rails Oracle enhanced adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I am having issue connecting from ROR 3.2 to Oracle database.

```
irb(main):001:0> gem 'ruby-oci8', "~>2.1.0"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.1'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> exit

rails console
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': 
Please install the oracle_enhanced adapter: `gem install activerecord-o
racle_enhanced-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter) (LoadError)
```

I searched the web and it says i should create a gems file located at 
https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/Gemfile and then do a bundle install .
But i am new to rails and not sure how to do this any ideas please.

C:\kerbapp>bundle show activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rails application since 3.0 comes integrated with package management for gems called bundler (I recommend [reading up more here](http://gembundler.com/)). Any application will see only the gems included in its package list.

Your project should have a `Gemfile` file - add the `gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.1'` line there, run `bundle` command from project root directory, and it should be good to go.

Keep in mind that when working with rails (and any sizable ruby project really) you should be adding all gems this way.